# How to construct negative time less than 1 hour using MAKETIME function of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, datetime, time, temporal

From MySQL dev site -

[MAKETIME function -](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime)

> - MAKETIME(hour,minute,second)
>
> Returns a time value calculated from the hour, minute, and second arguments.
>
> The second argument can have a fractional part.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(12,15,30);
>         -> '12:15:30'
> ```

Upon testing on my machine -

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(1, 0, 0) AS output;
+----------+
| output   |
+----------+
| 01:00:00 |
+----------+
```

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(1, 30, 0) AS output;
+----------+
| output   |
+----------+
| 01:30:00 |
+----------+
```

Now, trying to constructing negative time -

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(-1, 0, 0) AS output;
+-----------+
| output    |
+-----------+
| -01:00:00 |
+-----------+
```

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(-1, 30, 0) AS output;
+-----------+
| output    |
+-----------+
| -01:30:00 |
+-----------+
```

Now I try to construct the time `-00:30:00` using `MAKETIME` function. I try -

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(-0, 30, 0) AS output;
+----------+
| output   |
+----------+
| 00:30:00 |
+----------+
```

The result is not as intended. Then I try -

```
mysql> SELECT MAKETIME(0, -30, 0) AS output;
+--------+
| output |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
```

I am getting a null output here.

I can't figure out a proper way to do it.

Can I possibly do it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just experimenting with MySQL, I don't have any practical application for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a gap in maketime's functionality; the mariadb documentation outright says "If minute or second are out of the range 0 to 60, NULL is returned." which seems to be the behavior of all mysql and mariadb versions I can test.

I suggest you use sec_to_time instead:

```
sec_to_time((0)*3600 + (-30)*60 + (0))
```

Comment: A question slightly out of context, among official MuSQL and mariadb which one is more popular, which one is more widely used by individuals, which one is more widely used by industry?

Comment: They have different strengths and weaknesses.  Who cares about "industry"?  IMO the two greatest reasons for using mariadb are: 1) mysql is owned by Oracle, which has always been one of the greatest masters of vendor lock in and 2) mariadb sees steady development; mysql is erratic, with sometimes years going by without improvements

Comment: I think you should care about "industry" because it is the "industry" which gives you job. And in "industry" you don't enjoy personal freedom but have to work on whatever system provided by the system administrators.  Only freelancers can afford not to care about "industry".

Comment: I guess I was assuming from your question that you were in a position to make a decision, that is, someone who could tell the system administrators what they wanted.  If not, I'm not sure what the point of your question was

Comment: well the point being the one that is widely used in "industry" should be the preferred one to hone your skills on and use others only when you have free time

Comment: they are both used widely.  I believe pretty much all the linux distributions switched to mariadb by default (but you can certainly use either); amazon RDS supports both.  almost all skills you might be honing will apply to both.

Answer (score 1):

This function doesn't seem usable for this purpose. You'll probably need some string manipulation and a final cast, as in:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT_WS(':', '-0', 30, 0) AS TIME);
```

```
-00:30:00
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to be some not so desired purely temporal approach but merely string concatenation, the answer by @ysth seems to be more of a temporal approach.

Comment: @PayelSenapati It mostly depends on how you want to handle edge cases (e.g., do you want 70 minutes to render `NULL` or not).